# Couch ignores filters

Tags: couchdb

Following this [guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/design.html) I create a design document with one view in it:

```
"views":{
    "user":{
        "map":"function(doc){emit(doc.id,doc)}"
    }
}
```

If I then make a curl request like so:

```
curl .../_view/user
```

I get a result set, that looks like this:

```
{"total_rows":5,"offset":0,"rows":[{... value:{"_id":"...","login":"admin"}},...]}
```

If, however, I want to filter results by `login` field (now following this [guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html)), like so:

```
curl ... /_view/user?login="test_login"
or   ... /_view/user?login=test_login
```

I still get the very same result-set. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I change the view a little bit, so that login attribute is now a key:

```
"map":"function(doc){emit(doc.login,doc)}"
```

However, even in this case filtering stil does not work. Whether I do:

```
/_view/user?login="root"
```

or

```
/_view/user?login="blahblahblah"
```

Taking all this into account, I guess, my final question should be: `Does anybody in the world use CouchDB, if it is not working at all?` I played around with dozens of databases, and all of them work as I expect it. `CouchDB` is a major exception.

Comment: Well, actually, I found a solution. The idea is to use `key` instead of `login` in the url.

Comment: And to use `%22` instead of `"`. I guess there is a lot of such funky stuff down the road.